# Subtract two sum field and display in third field crystal report

Tags: math, crystal-reports, report, formula, operation

A and B are **SUM FIELD IN FOOTER SECTION** i want to get the values from that field and subtract A-B and the result to be dispalyed in C field USING FORMULA

I HAVE CREATED 2 FORMULA 
A.

```
WhilePrintingRecords ;
Global numberVar MD ;
if   {Command.TYPE} = "L" then
MD := MD + Sum ({Command.MDA},{Command.TYPE});
```

B.

```
Global numberVar MDB ;
if   {Command.TYPE} = "Z" then
MDB := MDB + Sum ({Command.MDA}, {Command.TYPE});
```

NOW HOW TO USE THIS VALUE AND FORM THIRD FORMULA TO CALCULATE
C= A-B

Comment: what is the purpose of adding `MD:=MD+` and `MDB:=MDB+` to your formulas?

Comment: Acutally i m storing those value and using them for performing calculation ie subtraction

Comment: If you are using in footer I don't see any use of recursive adding the values... remove those and try to use the formula

Answer (score 0):

create another formula and place inside the 2 global numbervars like below

`Global numberVar MD - Global numberVar MDB`

Comment: i have created third formula   Global numberVar final ;
 final :=Global numberVar MD - Global numberVar MDB but final variable is getting value 0.00

Comment: are you placing that formula in the same section or a section below than the others 2 are displayed? Are you using subreports? if so, you should use shared numbervar rather than global

Comment: i have created 2 groupfootersection1 and groupfootersection2   formula A is in   groupfootersection1  and   formula b is  in  groupfootersection2 and thre final result i want is in   groupfootersection2

Comment: check if formula shows a number if you place Global numberVar final ; final :=Global numberVar MD or Global numberVar final ; final :=Global numberVar MDB? Has MD different value than MDB?

Comment: here is the link of the image [link](http://s6.postimg.org/3ttan9lv5/Untitled.png)

Comment: based on your layout this should be working Global numberVar MD - Global numberVar MDB, Are MD and MDB different values? it might be returning 0  because they have the same value.

Comment: what about if you change from global to shared numbervar? you can create running totals rather than using global variables as well and then just do the subtraction between the 2 of them like #runnningTotalMD - #runningTotalMDB

Comment: i have  create running totals and did subtraction  like #runnningTotalMD - #runningTotalMDB  i noticed that i m getting value of  #runningTotalMD  and   #runningTotalMDB  both as 3501554.18  thats why i m getting result zero

Comment: i think #runnningTotalMD is in groupfootersection1 so the value is not coming #runnningTotalMD value should be 278580509